# Omitting non-trading data from plotting (zoo object)

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I have a zoo object which contains regular trading hours data. 
However when I try to plot it, I get breaks in the plots.

Is there any way I can eliminate them?

```
 2012-06-01 10:00:00 2012-06-01 10:01:00 2012-06-01 10:02:00 2012-06-01 10:03:00 
          -106.0788           -250.1170           -218.9439           -236.8216 
2012-06-01 10:04:00 2012-06-01 10:05:00 
          -258.8041           -253.7609
```

Comment: What do you mean, breaks in the plot?  Please use `dput` to provide a sample of data.  When I manually build something that looks like what you have provided, and I plot it with `plot`, I see a line with no breaks.

Comment: If you look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf, they have "omit weekends" while plotting zoo. However it does not work for me.

Comment: Actually I am too new, so it does now allow me to post plots/figures. Else i could have posted the plot.

Comment: here's something you may like even though it's not exactly what you asked for: if your zoo object is `x`, try this `require("quantmod"); chartSeries(x, theme='white')`